# Storing date and time in a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

```
struct Node
{
    int id;
    char name[25];
    int age;
    int No;
    int RoomNo;
    struct Node* next;
}*Test;

14;Jack;25;2445201;402;20/08/2020 11:00
```

That is the struct and content of the txt file. I want to store each data into linked list until a semicolon. But I couldn't store date should I divide the date or can I store it as one. Because I tried to store it as string but didn't work, I cant store it as integer aswell.

```
fscanf(Print, "%d;%[^;];%d;%d;%d", &Test->id, Test->name, &Test->age, &Test->No, &Test->RoomNo);
```

Comment: it is VERY error prone to declare a pointer to a struct via a `typedef`.  Suggest to declare the struct, then declare an instance of the struct, then declare a pointer to that instance.

Comment: The struct definition is missing (at least) two fields.  One for the date and one for the time.

Answer (score 0):

suggest:

```
struct Node
{
    int id;
    char name[25];
    int age;
    int No;
    int RoomNo;
    char date[11];
    char time[6];
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node myStruct;

struct Node *ptr2myStruct = &myStruct;
```

What are you using to extract the line of data?

Suggest:  1) use `fgets()` to input the whole line.  2) use `sscan()` or `strtok()`  to extract the fields from the whole line.